# Unable to extract tweet public metrics using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```py
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)
response = client.get_users_tweets(id=userID, tweet_fields='public_metrics')
```

The above runs successfully, but I got the below response without the metrics like the number of likes, comments, and retweets.

```py
Response(data=[<Tweet id=1699137915055546 text='Dogs are cute'>], includes={}, errors=[], meta={'result_count': 1, 'newest_id': '1699137915055546', 'oldest_id': '16991379150555'})
```

How can I get those public metrics?